# Windows azure exception of type "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException "

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2012, azure, neo4j

I have uploaded a MVC WEB Api solution in windows azure with Neo4j virtual machine.But always get 500 Internal Server Error given below.

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(EndPoint localEP)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)"}
```

How to resolve this?Any one please help me.

Sample ajax request given below

```
 $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: config.url() + 'api/Picture/ShowImage?url=' + imgId() + '&userid=' + localStorage.userid,
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            // data: value,
            success: function (data) {



            }
        }).fail(
                function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                    //alert(err);
                });
```

Comment: when did u get this when upload solution or database?

Comment: I have uploaded successfully,and the site is available.I got this error on some ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure Azure Endpoints within VisualStudio when the project was created? There is a separate configuration pane for IP endpoints. How do you invoke your ajax calls? Can you post some code?

Regards,
Martin

Comment: How to configure Azure Endpoints within VisualStudio?I dont know how to do it.I have uploaded the project by publishing it and uploaded the published content via FTP not directly from visual studio.I have updated the question by adding some sample ajax request.Please find it